# How to use the Microsoft Video API?

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I would like the user to insert the direct link of the Video such as http://www.video.com/test.mp4

And as soon as you click the "submit" button, you would consult the MICROSOFT VIDEO API JSON and get this information.

I was able to create one for the Images and I'll be making the code available here, but I'm having a lot of trouble creating for the video.

I would also like to know if I can get this information through "Live Streams", as per example of IP's of online cameras.

**VÍDEO**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "sensitivityLevel": "{string}",
            "frameSamplingValue": "{number}",
            "detectionZones": "{string}",
            "detectLightChange": "{boolean}",
            "mergeTimeThreshold": "{number}",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/video/v1.0/detectmotion?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","INSERT KEY");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**IMAGE - WORKING**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TESTANDO DETECTOR DE FACE EM FOTOS</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function processImage() {
        // **********************************************
        // *** Update or verify the following values. ***
        // **********************************************

        // Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
        var subscriptionKey = "INSERT KEY";

        // Replace or verify the region.
        //
        // You must use the same region in your REST API call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.
        // For example, if you obtained your subscription keys from the westus region, replace
        // "westcentralus" in the URI below with "westus".
        //
        // NOTE: Free trial subscription keys are generated in the westcentralus region, so if you are using
        // a free trial subscription key, you should not need to change this region.
        var uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";

        // Request parameters.
        var params = {
            "returnFaceId": "true",
            "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
            "returnFaceAttributes": "age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise",
        };

        // Display the image.
        var sourceImageUrl = document.getElementById("inputImage").value;
        document.querySelector("#sourceImage").src = sourceImageUrl;

        // Perform the REST API call.
        $.ajax({
            url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),

            // Request headers.
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            },

            type: "POST",

            // Request body.
            data: '{"url": ' + '"' + sourceImageUrl + '"}',
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
            $("#responseTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        })

        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Display error message.
            var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ? "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
            errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" : (jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message) ? 
                jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message : jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).error.message;
            alert(errorString);
        });
    };
</script>

<h1>Detectar Faces:</h1>
Entre com a URL para <strong>Analisar o Rosto</strong>.
<br><br>
Imagem para Analise: <input type="text" name="inputImage" id="inputImage" value="" />
<button onclick="processImage()">Analizar face</button>
<br><br>
<div id="wrapper" style="width:1020px; display:table;">
    <div id="jsonOutput" style="width:600px; display:table-cell;">
        Resposta
        <br><br>
        <textarea id="responseTextArea" class="UIInput" style="width:580px; height:400px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="imageDiv" style="width:420px; display:table-cell;">
        Imagem Utilizada
        <br><br>
        <img id="sourceImage" width="400" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to know if I can get this information through "Live Streams", as per example of IP's of online cameras.

According the document of [Video API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/video/how-to/howtocallvideoapis#a-namestep2astep-2-upload-a-video-to-the-service-and-check-the-status), if we submit a link of a video. The video will be uploaded to the service for analyze. It is not suitable for Live Streams.

If you want to Analyze Videos in Real-time, you need to capture frames from video at your client side and analyze the video frame by frame. Here is a code sample of [Live Camera](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis/tree/master/Windows/LiveCameraSample) using C#.

Comment: But how do I do this in javascript and html5?

Comment: You need to look for a JavaScript library which could capture frames from the live streams and analyze these frames(images) using the working code for image you posted.

Comment: Can you give me a hand? I'm trying to do it for Web. And I'm missing out on this JSON's Video APIs. Not much information. I just need to do the same as the image, insert the url of the video and extract all the information and return the result.